# How to make home component ( home page ) as default page to display route in angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

### I have a problem in angular project
I have 3 components
header comp : nav links
footer comp : footer of website
home comp : diplay home page ( default in starting )

my app.component.html :

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>  /*Home component ?????*/
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

so how to configure app-routing module.ts to make home component display as default page when open website

Answer (score 0):

in your root routing Module you can go like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

you can also just match the empty path string to your home-component if you prefer that

Comment: after making your answer in my app-routing , home component not displayed  , only header and footer displayed

Comment: Where is you home component declared ? 
You have to show some more code before anyone can make more sense out of your problem and give you some helpfull answer

Comment: home component , header and footer  are inside app component

Comment: Im asking in which module did you declare them? 
I recommend you go with the angular introduction first
https://angular.io/tutorial 
There is also information about routing